# Cross Domain Session: Any thoughts on storing session id in JWT?

Tags: php, session, cross-domain, jwt

I am working on an PHP API application that will work an different domains (and hosted on different servers) that need to share user session. Let's say `api.a.com` and `api.b.com`.

Back end side, for me, storing session data using a `session id` key that can be fetch from multiple domain is the easy part.

My main concern is sending `session id` to both `api.a.com` and `api.b.com`. Native PHP session uses cookies to send session id for each request. Having different top level domain, the cookies will not be sent to all domains (unless I explicitly use Javascript to extract it and send it as a request header).

I thought about storing the `session id` inside the the `Json Web Token` data sent to the server, but somehow, it feels wrong.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a memcache server. PHP supports saving sessions in memcache.

With Amazon, I have a load balancer front with Linux instances, each connected to memcache.

Then I have a completely different EB application and domain that accesses the same memcache and pulls real time stats, so it's pretty easy to setup access to the same memcache server or cluster from different applications.

Note there's a difference between "memcache" and "memcached" -- either can be used, but they're different servers!

Comment: ... and, "as for *me,"* I've been so-far using "memcache**d**." (I welcome, and indeed invite, the educated opinions of anyone who might suggest to me that I have made the Wrong Choice ...)

Comment: memcache was the legacy in the app I picked up -- memcacheD is almost exactly the same, BUT it has a few features missing from memcache, like retrieving all data. You have to do a couple of loops and parses to get it from memcache.

Answer (score 1):

Use a memcache server. PHP supports saving sessions in memcache or mysql. 
 then use sessionid by http    transport.

`

$sid = $_REQUEST['sid'];// receive  sessionid

session_start();

session_id($sid);  //reset current sessionid by $sid

var_dump($_SESSION["A_DOMAIN_SESSION"]);

var_dump($_SESSION["B_DOMAIN_SESSION"]);

?>`

Comment: <?php  $sid = $_REQUEST['sid'];// receive sessionid
session_id($sid); //reset current sessionid by $sid
session_start();

var_dump($_SESSION["A_DOMAIN_SESSION"]);

var_dump($_SESSION["B_DOMAIN_SESSION"]);

?>